# Formula field to categorize records

Tags: formula-field

I am trying to create a formula which will help categorising customers based on the following conditions. I have created this formula which gives me this error " Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 2
"
I am sure I am doing something incorrectly here but unable to find out.

IF(Country__c="UK",
IF(AND(Field2__c >=100,Field3__c >=35),"A",
IF(AND(Field2__c >=100,Field3__c <35),"B",
"")))

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easier to format formulas with indents to see how many parameters each function has.

```
IF(Country__c="UK", 
    IF(AND(Field2__c >=100,Field3__c >=35),
        "A", 
        IF(AND(Field2__c >=100,Field3__c <35),
            "B", 
            ""
        )
    )
)
```

Looking at it this way, you can see that you don't have a 3rd argument for all your IFs. The IF for Country__c="UK" only has 2. You need to add an else there. I think this should do it.

```
IF(Country__c="UK", 
    IF(AND(Field2__c >=100,Field3__c >=35),
        "A", 
        IF(AND(Field2__c >=100,Field3__c <35),
            "B", 
            ""
        )
    ),
    "NOT UK"
)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. You were right that there was no else condition added. I have added it now and it works fine.